# How to auto-populate Close Date (End of this month) in Opportunity page in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, sfdc

I have a Requirement :

After clicking on New Opportunity Button it will open Opportunity page with some fields auto populated 
Like 
1. Close Date: default to creation date plus 30 ?
2. Opportunity Name:  default to ,

etc..

Could you please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use few approaches for implementing autopopulation field functionality:

- set up default values for your fields (note that if the default values are dynamic, e.g. val = f(x,y), then x,y must come from the running user or environment, not from other opportunity fields);
- create Visualforce page with custom Apex controller where to override of the Opportunity.New button;
- use workflows of triggers on save new record event.